# Creating a view creates a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a view that depends on a materialized view.
I have their definitions in a .sql file that cascade drops the materialized view.

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS mat_view_name CASCADE;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mat_view_name AS ...;

CREATE VIEW view_name AS
    SELECT ... FROM (
        SELECT ... FROM mat_view_name
        UNION
        SELECT ... from another_table
    )
;
```

I changed a SELECT statement inside the materialized view and when I execute the sql script in the migration, it changes my initial view to a table in my structure.sql.

Here's the new code I get in my structure.sql

```
CREATE TABLE view_name (
    ...
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY view_name REPLICA IDENTITY NOTHING;

CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS
ON SELECT TO view_name DO INSTEAD  SELECT .....;
```

If I rollback the migration I get the original code back :

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS...
```

I only added two JOIN statements in a select inside the materialized view.

My database version is 9.6.2.

Do you know why this is happening ?
Is it a performance issue, and PG decides to use this instead of a classic view ?
How to force it to create a view ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting this script from a dump or a backup of your database.

Materialized views are essentially tables created in a similar fashion to `CREATE TABLE AS` with the sql being stored in the database so it can be refreshed.

The default behaviour when dumping a `materialized view` is to dump as a table.

[CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW: documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)